# Remove sub set of rows from the original dataframe using Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframes as below

DF1 - contains past 1 month data

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string(nullable = true)
 |-- age: string (nullable = true)
 |-- createdDate: long (nullable = false)
 |-- school: string(nullable = true)
```

DF2 - contains todays data

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string(nullable = true)
 |-- age: string (nullable = true)
 |-- createdDate: long (nullable = false)
 |-- school: string(nullable = true)
```

Since these dataframes contains details of students across different schools , to identify unique rows always id and school columns should be used. I want to remove all student details available in DF2 from DF1 based on id and school. Im not sure how to do this using pyspark.

```
joined_df = DF1.join(DF2, (DF1.id == DF2.id) & (DF1.school == DF2.school).select('*')
joined_df = joined_df.dropDuplicates()
```

I wrote the above code. But later I realised this will just remove duplicates where it will leave the original dataset in DF1. How can I achieve my requirment?

Answer (score 0):

A classical way to update a dataframe is to apply changes on itself. It's the same to remove row: you need to filter on desired data... or exclude what you do not need.
The key will be to identify rows to be removed: this will be done thanks to a join based on school that will populate an additional column according to IDs values. A left join will ensure you will keep rows from other schools and I will rename df2.id to make it different from df1.id.
The steps will be the following:

- Prepare df2 for the join: keep necessary columns, rename id
- left join to add id2 column to df1
- add a column with the result of the comparison between id and id2
- filter on columns where ids are different
- remove columns added to obtain the result

It will looks something like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2_new = df2.select(df2.id.alias("id2"), df2.school)

df1 = df1.join(df2_new, DF1.school == DF2.school, how='left') \
      .withColumn('to_remove', F.when(df1.id == DF1.id2, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)) \
      .filter(df1.to_remove != 1) \
      .drop('id2', 'to_remove')
```

Comment: I am getting 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_remove' error with the above solution

Comment: Sorry, my bad: I forgot a `)`. I edited the post accordingly, I also added an `otherwise()` clause to secure